# Why is this configuration redirecting www.sec.com to www.domain1.com?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.domain1.com
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/home/"
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/awstats /var/www/cgi-bin/awstats
Alias /awstats /var/www/html/awstats
Alias /myadmin /var/www/html/myadmin
ScriptAlias /mailman/ /var/www/cgi-bin/mailman/
Alias /pipermail/ /var/mailman/archives/public/
Alias /horde /var/www/html/horde
SuexecUserGroup webadmin webadmin
ServerAdmin "webadmin@domain1.com"
ScriptAlias "/cgi-bin/" "/home/webadmin/domain1.com/cgi-bin/"
CustomLog "/home/webadmin/domain1.com/access_log" "combined"
ErrorLog "/home/webadmin/domain1.com/error_log"
<Directory /home/webadmin/domain1.com/html>
Options Includes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.sec.com
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/home/sec"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/awstats /var/www/cgi-bin/awstats
Alias /awstats /var/www/html/awstats
Alias /myadmin /var/www/html/myadmin
ScriptAlias /mailman/ /var/www/cgi-bin/mailman/
Alias /pipermail/ /var/mailman/archives/public/
Alias /horde /var/www/html/horde
ServerName www.domain1.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/home/
SuexecUserGroup webadmin webadmin
ServerAdmin "webadmin@domain1.com"
ScriptAlias "/cgi-bin/" "/home/webadmin/domain1.com/cgi-bin/"
CustomLog "/home/webadmin/domain1.com/access_log" "combined"
ErrorLog "/home/webadmin/domain1.com/error_log"
SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.crt/domain1.com.hspc.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.key/domain1.com.hspc.key
SSLEngine on
<Directory /home/webadmin/domain1.com/html>
Options Includes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

is not redirecting to www.domain1.com you need to send into your request the proper header where Host: is the www.sec.com

```
curl -H 'Host:www.sec.com' http://YOUR_IP
```

or have it into the host file.

Comment: Thanks for helping! So I have 2 options: add header to my web pages OR have something in my .htaccess file ? thank you